# Apply new theme for a particular view without recreating Activity

Tags: android, android-theme

My application has 6 fragments displayed at once, so recreating activity is not a good option cause it makes the screen blink and face some unexpected issues regrading saving and restoring state of activities and fragments.

I also don't want to traverse the view hierarchy and change every view cause there are many attributes need to change.

All I need is just apply a new theme (style) for the `NavigationView` which is hidden aside of the screen and will be shown latter. In particular, I want to change these attributes:

`itemBackground`, `itemIconTint`, `itemTextColor`

Comment: Just the `NavigationView` itself? Nothing else in the `Activity`?

Comment: @MikeM. Only NavigationView and its child views. I also need to change other views as well. But it's not a matter cause they are needed to change just the background.

Comment: That should be relatively simple. Put the `NavigationView` into its own separate layout file, and `<include>` it in your `Activity`'s layout to begin with. When you need to change themes, first remove the existing one – `drawerLayout.remove(navigationView)`. Then create a `ContextThemeWrapper` with the new theme, get a `LayoutInflater` from that – `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(ctx, R.style.Theme_New))` – and inflate that `NavigationView` layout back into the `DrawerLayout` – `inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_view, drawerLayout)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)

I solved the issue using his way:

```
public void updateNavigationViewLayout(){
    drawerLayout.removeView(navigationView);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.newtheme));
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer, drawerLayout);
    navigationView = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
}
```

Remember to refer navigationView to the new one. Otherwise, on the second time calling this method, the new NagivationView won't be removed and you will add one extra NavigationView leading to this error:

```
Child drawer has absolute gravity LEFT but this DrawerLayout already has a drawer view along that edge
```

Comment: Yep, I was just writing a comment to mention that issue, after I'd tested it myself. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Don't forget to set the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on the new `NavigationView` instance, as well as any other listeners, state values, etc., you might've had set on other things, too; e.g., header `View`s. Just occurred to me.